# Sums of sets of lower density 0

Tags: nt.number-theory

We say that a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ has *lower density 0* if $$\text{lim inf}_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n} = 0.$$

Given $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we set $A+B = \{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$.

Are there $A, B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ with lower density 0, but $A+B$ does not have lower density 0?

Comment: If this would not exist, how would anybody believe the Goldbach conjecture.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is relatively easy to prove that the set of perfect squares has asymptotic density equal to $0$. Then either the set $Q_2 := \{x^2+y^2: x,y \in \mathbf N\}$ has positive lower asymptotic density, and we're done, or the lower density of $Q_2$ is zero, and then we just consider that $\mathbf N = Q_2 + Q_2$ (by Lagrange's four-squares theorem).

By the way, it follows, e.g., from E. Landau, *Über die Einteilung der positiven ganzen Zahlen in vier Klassen nach der Mindeszahl der zu ihrer additiven Zusammensetzung erforderlichen Quadrate*, Arch. Math. Phys. **13** (1908), 305-312 that the asymptotic density of $Q_2$ is actually zero, but this is more than what you need to answer the question in the OP.

Comment: Very elegant - reminds me of the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Comment: @Dominic van der Zypen - Do you perhaps mean the proof that there are irrational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^b$ is rational? That proof typically goes by choosing $a = b = \sqrt{2}$ and then splitting into two cases based on whether or not $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is a proof that the asymptotic density of $Q_2$ is zero, which doesn't depend on Landau's result: http://mathoverflow.net/a/205866/16537.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston you are absolutely right, I meant that one.

Answer (score 9):

Let $A$ be the set of all natural numbers having digit $0$ in every odd-numbered place (counting from the decimal point), and let $B$ be the set of all numbers having a $0$ in every even-numbered place. Then $A$ and $B$ have density $0$, while $A+B=\mathbb N\setminus(A\cup B)$ has density $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Partition $\mathbb N$ into two sets $S$ and $T$, each having lower density $0$ and upper density $1$; for example, by taking
$$S=[1!,2!)\cup[3!,4!)\cup[5!,6!)\cup[7!,8!)\cup\cdots,$$
$$T=[2!,3!)\cup[4!,5!)\cup[6!,7!)\cup[8!,9!)\cup\cdots.$$
Now define
$$A=\{n\in\mathbb N:n+1\in S\}\cup\{1\},$$
$$B=\{n\in\mathbb N:n+1\in T\}\cup\{1\}.$$
Then each of the sets $A,B$ has lower density $0$ (and upper density $1$), and $A+B=\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}.$