# Suprema of lower density of sums and products of sets with lower density 0

Tags: nt.number-theory

We define the *lower density* of a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ by
$$
  \operatorname{ld}(A) \ := \ \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{n}.
$$
For $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we set
$$
  A + B \ := \ \{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\},
$$
and similarly
$$
  A \cdot B \ := \ \{a\cdot b: a\in A, b\in B\}.
$$
Further let ${\cal P}_0(\mathbb{N}) := \{A\in{\cal P}(\mathbb{N}): \operatorname{ld}(A) = 0\}$ be the set of all sets of positive integers
whose lower density is $0$.

**Question:** What are

- $\text{sup}\{\text{ld}(A+B): A,B\in {\cal P}_0(\mathbb{N})\}$, and
- $\text{sup}\{\text{ld}(A\cdot B): A,B\in {\cal P}_0(\mathbb{N})\}$?

Comment: The first one is certainly 1. For a trivial construction, let $n_1\ll n_2\ll n_3\ll\ldots$. Then if $A=[n_1,n_2]\cup [n_3,n_4]\cup [n_5,n_6]$ while $B=\{0\}\cup [n_2,n_3]\cup [n_4,n_5]\cup\ldots$, their union is everything, but both have lower density 0.

Comment: Many thanks, Anthony - do you want to post your construction as a (partial) answer?

Comment: Your first question is answered by some of the answers to [this old question of yours](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/205843/sums-of-sets-of-lower-density-0), for instance, [this answer of mine](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/205843/sums-of-sets-of-lower-density-0/205856#205856).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anthony Quas has already answered the first part.
The second supremum is $1$ as well -- just let $A$ be the set of
positive integers all of whose prime divisors are $2$ or
$\equiv 1 (\!\!\mod 4)$, and let  $B$ be the set of positive integers
all of whose prime divisors are $\equiv 3 (\!\!\mod 4)$.
Then $A \cdot B = \mathbb{N}$.